# How do I add particle.js background to this website template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, background

How do I add a particle.js (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) background to this website template? I'm not able to figure out where the background picture is being called.

Here's the template: https://html5up.net/dimension

Please let me know!
Thanks

Note: I've bought the license if it matters

Comment: I would assume you will need to remove the images in each of those articles.  And then apply the particles to the BODY tag.

Answer (score 0):

The background image was inserted via css and is in a div with the class called "bg".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl1Iz.png)

To add these particles, you will have to add the script and then create a json passing the particles settings.

```
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/bGxvQd
```

Comment: but it's never importing or calling the image right?

would you be able to make a sample in a sandbox for reference?